# namespacing a JavaScript class but retaining the same 'this'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a fairly large node.js client library and I'd like to be able to 'namespace' portions of it to keep it more organized.  For example:

```
var client = new Client(config);

client.activities.get(activityId, function(activity) {
     ...
});

...

client.user.get(userId, function(user) {
     ...
});
```

I'm currently trying to do something like this in the module:

```
function Client(config) {
    this.config = config;
}

Client.prototype.activities = require('./activities');
Client.prototype.user = require('./user');

module.exports = Client;
```

but when 'get' is called in the activities 'submodule', the "this" is for the module, of course, and not the outer Client function.  Basically, both of the submodules need access to the outer configuration information ('config' in this example).  What is the best practice around doing this in node.js?

Comment: I use to set a variable outside the method setting the value to this. I dont know if there is a better practice, but maybe solve your problem

Comment: You'd need a wrapper method which is invoked in the context you want `Client.prototype.activities_method = function (foo) {return this.activities[foo].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a modeling issue with the plan you have is that `new X()` copies each property reference of `X.prototype` to the new item; for instance, `X.myFunction` is the exact same reference as `X.prototype.myFunction`; but does NOT create a new *copy* of `myFunction`.

It sounds like if `activities` is a part of a Client (the same way `StreetAddress` might be), you actually want `activities` to be a Class, not a module, and for `Client` to create a *new* instance of it when it's constructed. That's not really something that `prototype` is useful for. If I'm wrong, maybe you could show an example of a basic operation `activities` would be used for.

Comment: I'm not a pro or anything, but i believe the usage of Class and Instance is a bit off when talking about JavaScript since it's prototype-based and not an Object-oriented language.

Comment: @Arg0n It's not the go-to mechanism the way a language like Java uses them, but JavaScript does *have* objects. It even has classes if you have either a framework to structure them (eg Dojo, TypeScript) or ES6.

Comment: I think I agree with you - these should just be subobjects and I should pass in the config to each of them at initialization.